# Mention how many votes it takes to delete an answer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

We recently had a question on our meta regarding deletion of posts. I wanted to send the user to the page in the help center that explains the "vote to delete" process.

While looking up the information, I noticed that it is explained that ["It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question."](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-questions), no such information is given in regards to [*answers*](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers) though.

Thus, I propose adding the information to the relevant help center page.

Comment: If you propose then I think this should be better tagged [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi: If you think the question should be tagged differently, [edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/204170/edit) it. I didn't consider a help center addition much of a "feature".

Comment: Basically anything only (mods and?) devs can do is a feature request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong help topic. You want: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers)

Of course, this was *also* missing any information on the number of delete votes required. I'm not entirely convinced this sort of minutia is necessary for such high-level help topics, but since it already existed in the topic for questions I've added it for now to be consistent.

Comment: This is why I linked to the *answers* page in my question... anyway, thanks for adding it ;)

Comment: I'm supposed to follow *all* the links now? Bah...